# Present value of the cosmological scale factor, important or arbitrary?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, scales

I'm now confused about a subject that I thought was very clear to me, until recently.  So I need to sort this clearly once and for all.  Consider the standard FLRW cosmology in classical general relativity, with the following well known **Robertson-Walker metric** (many are writting this metric using another radial coordinate, but this is irrelevant):
$$\tag{1}
ds^2 = dt^2 - \frac{a^2(t)}{(1 + \frac{1}{4} \, k \, r^2)^2} (dr^2 + r^2 \, d\Omega^2).
$$
I use the convention of *unitless radial coordinates*, while the scale factor has units of length: $a(t) \sim \mathrm{L}$.  The curvature of space is determined by the *unitless parameter* $k = -1, 0, 1$ (since the radial coordinate $r$ has no unit).  The Riemann curvature tensor has the following components (in a local orthonormal frame):
\begin{align}
R_{0110} = R_{0220} = R_{0330} &= -\, \frac{\ddot{a}}{a}, \tag{2} \\[1ex]
R_{1221} = R_{2332} = R_{3113} &= \frac{\dot{a}^2}{a^2} + \frac{k}{a^2}, \tag{3}
\end{align}
Now my confusion is about the physical status of the value $a_0 \equiv a(t_0)$, i.e the *present value of the cosmological scale factor*.  I frequently read that $a_0$ is an arbitrary constant that has no physical meaning.  This is clear for the flat space case ($k = 0$), since we could absorb it in the radial coordinate: $a_0 \, r \Rightarrow \tilde{r}$ (and most authors are considering the flat case only in their papers).

But then, if $k \ne 0$, that factor cannot be absorbed into the radial coordinate anymore since the transformation $a_0 \, r \Rightarrow \tilde{r}$ will bring it back into the geometric factor of the metric (1) (i.e $k \Rightarrow k / a_0^2$, while keeping $k = -1, 0, 1$).  And more importantly, according to the Riemann components (3) above, the factor $a_0 \sim \mathrm{L}$ set the **curvature scale** at time $t_0$, so it does have a important physical meaning when $k \ne 0$ (unless I'm missing something).

Of course, time $t_0$ is arbitrary in itself (the cosmological time the central observer is doing his observations).  But that observer could measure the curvature of space (and then $a_0$) by using the data from other observers.

So my question is just this:  Does $a_0$ have a real physical meaning on its own (the *radius of space curvature at present time* $t_0$), or is it really arbitrary and has no physical meaning at all, even for $k = \pm 1$?  If it doesn't have any physical meaning, how can we justify this, considering the curvature components (3)?

---

**Edit:**  The answer is now clear and is described in the big black book "Gravitation", of MTW (Misner-Thorne-Wheeler), at bottom of page 721 and page 722 (section 27.6).  It is exactly like what I believed, that $a_0$ do have an absolute meaning when $k \ne 0$.  The scale factor $a_0$ isn't arbitrary at all, unlike what many people and authors appear to say/write (they are probably thinking about the flat case only, $k = 0$)!

Comment: Hint: by $k = \pm 1$, one implicitly assumes the spacial curvature is anchored to some curvature radios $R_0$. You have the leeway to redefine $R_0$

Comment: @MadMax, if $k = \pm 1$, then how could you redefine $a_0$ (or your $R_0$)?  Once you defined the curvature parameter $k$ as $\pm 1$, then $a_0$ should have an absolute meaning (i.e the radius of curvature of space at time $t_0$).  Then $a_0$ cannot be arbitrary.  Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: My bad, you are right. Once one sets $k = \pm 1$, the $a_0$ (of length dimension) has an absolute meaning of radius $R_0$ of space curvature (not to be conflated with space-time curvature). Mind you that space curvature radius $R_0$ is a constant,   while $a(t)$ is not. Therefore $a(t)$ equals the constant space curvature radius $R_0$ **only at present time $t=t_0$**.